# Is it possible to retrofit TPM based disk encryption on system upgraded to 23.10?

Tags: boot, encryption, luks, tpm

There was a lot of rumour about TPM base disk encryption available on Ubuntu 23.10, but looks like all articles meant installation process.

Is it possible to retrofit TPM based encryption (effectively the key typing stage) on the upgraded OS instance with already encrypted drives? I'd like to stop typing password every time the system boots.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do with out a reinstall. Ubuntu 23.10 TPM is setup during the system install. It replaces some system components with snaps from Ubuntu Core.

See this article that describes how it works:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/tpm-backed-full-disk-encryption-is-coming-to-ubuntu

> TPM-backed FDE on classic Ubuntu Desktop systems is based on the same architecture as Ubuntu Core, and it shares a number of its design and implementation principles. Namely, the bootloader (shim and GRUB) and kernel assets will be delivered as snap packages (via gadget and kernel snaps), as opposed to being delivered as Debian packages. As such, it is the Snapd agent which will be responsible for managing full disk encryption throughout its lifecycle.
> The bootloader logic includes boot mode selection and kernel selection, and is encoded in the GRUB configuration which is provided by Snapd, rather than being automatically generated on the device. Finally, we will make use of Unified kernel images, where the kernel and initramfs will be encapsulated in a single PE binary containing a small stub to execute the kernel. This will be signed as a single artefact.
> TPM-backed FDE on classic Ubuntu Desktop systems is based on the same architecture as Ubuntu Core, and it shares a number of its design and implementation principles. Namely, the bootloader (shim and GRUB) and kernel assets will be delivered as snap packages (via gadget and kernel snaps), as opposed to being delivered as Debian packages. As such, it is the Snapd agent which will be responsible for managing full disk encryption throughout its lifecycle.
> The bootloader logic includes boot mode selection and kernel selection, and is encoded in the GRUB configuration which is provided by Snapd, rather than being automatically generated on the device. Finally, we will make use of Unified kernel images, where the kernel and initramfs will be encapsulated in a single PE binary containing a small stub to execute the kernel. This will be signed as a single artefact.
> Beyond the kernel and bootloader, the rest of your operating system, namely its userspace, will be exactly that of a classic Ubuntu environment.
> Beyond the kernel and bootloader, the rest of your operating system, namely its userspace, will be exactly that of a classic Ubuntu environment.

Comment: Thanks.
As I'm not fan of snaps and them turning Ubuntu far away from Debian, I think I'll pass on this solution even in future. I found guides how to make LUKS use TPM 2.0 and I'll try them.